# alternative to iframe in Ext.window

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a large html file that I want to download by opening new window. I am currently using iframe which is making the process long, slow and is also blocking the application. Can someone suggest me an alternative to iframe?
plase see below code

```
   var window = new Ext.Window({
                title: "download",
                height: 100,
                layout: 'fit',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'component',

                    autoEl: {
                            tag: 'iframe',
                            src: 'largedata.html'

                        }
                    }]
            }).show();
```

Comment: Alternative in what sense? If you just want to load the content you could make an Ajax request to pull in the data. It depends on what the page does.

Comment: the html url downloads excel file. do you think I can use ajax for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `XMLHttpRequest` and hidden dom element.

Example:

```
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                var name = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
                var filename = name.split("Attachment;filename=")[1];
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response); // xhr.response is a blob
                a.download = filename; // Set the file name.
                a.style.display = 'none';
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
                delete a;
            }
        };
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.send();
```

Parameter `url` is path to file.

Edit 2020-04-17:

Alternative you can just open window :

```
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Comment: is this way possible for downloading .xlsx file?

Comment: Yes it's possible

Comment: can you please tek me how @norbeq maybe give an example

Comment: What is unclear to you? You must replace `url` parameter with xlsx path. Like `xhr.open('GET', "http://example.xyz", true);`.

Comment: i replaced url with xlsx path but file is not getting downloaded.. is it because I need to using something instead of 'blob' as response type?